# How do I make taskbar icons the same size as on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading to Windows 10, the taskbar icons look cramped together:

> [image: comparison between Windows 8 and Windows 10]

How do I make it look like on Windows 8?

Comment: I don't use windows, but I think you may be able to grab the top of the task-bar and resize it. You may first have to enable editing of the task bar.

Comment: @richard that just gives me 2 rows for icons.

Comment: Changing DPI setting of screen may do it; it probably will affect fonts, and lots of other things as well though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to do this without 3rd-party modifications. I looked and looked, but the best I could find was 7+ Taskbar Tweaker. It enlarges the icons back to the size you're used to:

[image]

(No underline and modified icon images are not from 7+ Taskbar Tweaker)

As for the start menu, ClassicShell lets you upload a custom start menu icon, which seems to do the trick. It's packed with a lot more features than that though, and while you can disable them (i.e. custom start menu), I'm not sure if it'd be your cup of tea if you're only going to use a single part of it.

Comment: It looks like 7+ Taskbar Tweaker doesn't do this automatically. You have to right click the system tray icon, click "Advanced Options", scroll down to the bottom, and enable w10_large_icons.

Comment: this is a serious PITA.  7TT and others are obviously changing something to make this happen.  what are they changing and why is it not persistent?  my frustration is its one more damn utility running and it'd be nice to not have to deal with that and, apologies to the software authors, just FIX the bloody problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the bar and choose Properties from the menu. Remove the check from "Use small taskbar buttons" and then Click Apply.

If what you want is more space between the icons themselves, you'd have to apply some kind of third-party skin.

Comment: Icons are smaller than in Windows 8 even with this unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

To change the size of icons in general go to Settings -> Display and there is a slide bar that lets you do this. Hope that helps :)